# not able to find android wear source tree code

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm not able to find the android wear source code 4.4w(API 20).
I checked in git source tree and http://androidxref.com/.

I'm also not able to find the source code for [android.support.wearable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/package-summary.html) API

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting

Answer (score 0):

It's not open-source, at this time.

Comment: Thank's Aladin, "It's not open-source" :( is there is any link to support this, I'm not found anything about it. If you provide any reference document that help me lot. ---Thank you ---

Comment: There are no sources available for, per example, "WearableListView" in the sources for Android SDK.
See also the AOSP repository and the appropriate branches: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+refs
The kernel, however, is open-source for obvious license reason.

Comment: "at this time." Are there any rumors or indication or precedent to suggest that it will become open-source at some point?